# Right way to prove Asymptotic notations

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have always been confused with this and I wanted to clarify this.

How exactly do you prove that an asymptotic notation is true?

Example 1:

> sin(n) = Ω(cos(n))
>
> What I have been doing is to rewrite the question into the big-omega
> form which says:
>
> f(n) >= c * g(n) for all n >= n0
>
> Which is: sin(n) >= c * cos(n)
>
> I then proceed to randomly find an n and c that makes the equation
> true.
>
> In this case, I found c = 5, n = 3 which makes:
>
> sin(3) >= 5 x cos(3) true

Another example 2:

> 2^squareroot(lgn) = ω(lgn)
>
> I tried n = 5 and c = 6 as well as n = 6 and c = 5, and both yielded
> false, however, the answer is actually true.

However, I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it, because I managed to make it true while the answer says that it is false.

I believe I've been doing it all wrong by 'guessing the n and c' values to make the equation true. When I watch some youtube videos, they seem to be shifting equations around using algebra, before guessing a value for n, and I am not sure how to do it for this instance.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: The key phrase that you missed is *"for all n >= n0"*. You only get to choose `n0`. And then every `n` larger than `n0` must satisfy f(n) > c * g(n). That's false for sin(n) and cos(n) because at every multiple of /2, one of them is 0 and the other is not.

Comment: @user3386109 Ahh I see the problem now. Does it mean, the way to solve it is definitely still guessing/finding the right n0 and c values? However some people use a bit of algebra to help easily determine the values or something?